# Is it possible to upgrade Cassandra 2.2.19 directly to 3.11?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm planning to upgrade my 100+ nodes cassandra baremetal cluster with current version 2.2.19.
Please let me know if I can upgrade from 2.2.19 to 3.11 directly ?
Also what is the timeline to wait to upgrade to next version i.e from 3.11 -> 4.x, can I upgrade to the latest version  ( 2.2.19 -> 3.11 -> 4.x ) in single upgrade plan ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an issue upgrading a Cassandra 2.2.19 cluster directly to the latest 3.11 release.

There is no requirement to have a break to upgrade to C* 4.x -- upgrading the nodes isn't going to be an issue at all. What you need to be concerned with is whether you need to upgrade the driver you're using.

If you do need to upgrade the driver, you need to refactor your application if the new version of the driver is not binary-compatible with the old version. For example, upgrading from Java driver 3.x to 4.x has breaking changes (see the [Java driver v4 Upgrade Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/upgrade_guide/) for details).

Before upgrading your cluster, make sure you familiarise yourself with the upgrade instructions for the various releases:

- [Cassandra 3.11 NEWS.txt](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt)
- [Cassandra 4.0 NEWS.txt](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/NEWS.txt)
- [Cassandra 4.1 NEWS.txt](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/NEWS.txt)

Comment: In addition to this, can I run 2.2.19 in one data center and 4.0 in the other data center without issues?  
1. First DC upgrade from 2.2.19 to 3.11 then 3.11 to 4.0 
2. Meanwhile the second DC is still in 2.2.19
3. Monitor first DC in 4.0 and second DC in 2.2.19 for some time
4. If everything looks good proceed with second DC upgrade